# Why does a function allow a mutation of a global variable without returning it?

Tags: python, function, scope

I have a question about variable scope in Python. Why is a mutation of a variable allowed without returning the mutated variable?

```
def mutation(L):
    L.append("x")

L = []
mutation(L)
print(L)
```

I would expect this to print [], as the mutation of L inside the function only affects the local scope. Why is "L" mutated even in the global scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Python is pass by object reference, when you pass something to a function it points to the same object in memory that you can manipulate. If you want a function to not modify the original list, you need to make a copy of it when passing it to the function or inside of the function itself.

Sending a copy to the function:

```
def mutation(L):
    L.append("x")

L = []
mutation(list(L))
print(L)
# Prints out []
```

Making a copy inside the function:

```
def mutation(L):
    L = list(L)
    L.append("x")

L = []
mutation(L)
print(L)
# Prints out []
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are actually changing the original list/object passed into the function. Note that the underlying principle is *pass-by-object-reference*. So changes to the passed parameter within the function will reflect outside.

If you don't want to change globally, use `[:]` to create a copy and this would perform operations on the copy without mutating the original list.

```
def mutation(L):
    L = L[:]
    L.append("x")

L = []
mutation(L)
print(L)
# []
```